# In AngularJS is $scope actually the parent object's body?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

In AngularJS is `$scope` actually the parent object's body?  If so, does this mean that the controller in the image below (called "MainCtrl") is essentially setting two variables within the MODULE and that "categories" and "bookmarks" would now be available within the module called "Eggly?"

OR...

Is the function, passed in as the 2nd argument of the `controller` function actually NEWING UP a new empty object and passing that new object in as the `$scope`?  That would indicate that the two variables are being set on the new object and the new object, with the new variables, would be set as the controller.

**From a C# perspective**
In C# it is common to pass in "this" when creating an instance of an object within an object IF the child needs to access the parent.  The child would receive this and have access to any PUBLIC properties or methods.  It appears that passing in `$scope` does something similar except that EVERYTHING in the parent is available from the child (probably a function).

[image]

Comment: First part: NO, they will be available on the controller which is a component of the module. a module could have as many controllers (Not recommended though).

Comment: So, if the variables are going to be set on instance of the new object, then $scope would not be needed here.  Correct?

Comment: OH, WAIT!  $scope would not be needed to SET the two variables INTERNALLY.  Adding $scope basically declares them as PUBLIC so that something using the controller can see them.  Is THAT correct?  [sigh]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting a property on `$scope` exposes the property to whoever sees this scope, typically child directives and controllers.

It doesn't set it "on the module" - whatever that means.

Comment: You could argue that the visibility of something on a scope is in every case limited by the `$rootScope` -- which is per-module, aka per `ng-app`.

Comment: @yerforkferchips, I don't understand your comment. Module is not the same as `ng-app`. Module is just a collection of directives, controllers, services, etc... Scope is a function of where a particular controller or directive appears in the DOM. And `ng-app` is a directive to tell Angular where to bootstrap the app.